# Restore Windows 8.1 System Image Backup to new Boot Camp partition

Tags: backup, bootcamp, windows

I just got a new hard drive because the old one was going bad. I made a system image backup of the old Boot Camp partition and saved it to an external drive.

Got the new drive set up, with Mavericks, ran bootcamp and got a partition set up, installed windows 8.1 on it, and then tried restoring it from the image. When I get into the system restore I can choose the backup location, but the next step where you choose/format/partition the drive looks like it needs some kind of disk driver, but I don't know where to find a MacBook disk driver.

I'm hoping to restore so I don't end up having to reinstall everything.

Comment: What specifically is "system restore" - is it software that runs on Windows? What OS are you hoping to use to run the "restore"? What steps did you follow to make the "system image backup" in the first place? If I saw this earlier, I mightg suggest migration to superuser.com, but it's too late for that...

Comment: @bmike Yeah, it's been a really long time. I don't even remember how I resolved it. System restore is a part of Windows setup, to put it back to factory settings, I think.

Answer (score 1):

if you already installed WIN8.1 how or why would you also restore a backup image as well?

it seems like that is what is going on based on "next step where you choose/format/partition the drive" would indicate an attempt to restore the backup image on the new WIN8 install partition. btw, did you use winclone?

Comment: I did it through System Image Backup.

Comment: I tried doing it off of a recovery usb and then the windows 8.1 dvd first, but ran into the same problem of it not seeing the disk as a viable install location. I installed windows 8.1 in the hopes that it would allow me to do a restore from there, but apparently it doesn't work that way. I borrowed the 8.1 install disk from a friend, but now I'm thinking I'm going to have to do it over again because it doesn't like my Windows 8 key. I'm still looking for my Windows 8 disk, and I'm recollecting all my install media.